# Const member function Changing Object Data Member

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, ostream

Hi i am reading a book and have one doubt under section of const member funcitons. The code is as follows:

```
class Screen {
public:
    // display overloaded on whether the object is const or not
    Screen &display(std::ostream &os)
        { do_display(os); return *this; }
    const Screen &display(std::ostream &os) const
        { do_display(os); return *this; }
private:
    // function to do the work of displaying a Screen
    void do_display(std::ostream &os) const
    {os<<contents;}

};
```

My question is at the last line, it is written that **os<<contents** but since do_display is a const member function how can it modify the data member contents which is of type std::string?
Again **contents** is a private data member of the class Screen and as you can see in the example contents has been changed inside a const member function. How is this happening ? Doesn't const mean that we can't change any data member of the class? Is there a typo in the book or am i missing something? For reference i am attaching the screenshot  from the book where i have highlighted this part.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: That statement reads from `contents`. `os` is "modified", not contents.

Comment: "as you can see in the example contents has been changed...", no, I don't see that it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `os` is not a member of your class, that’s not a problem. The classes’ members are not changed in that statement.

The `contents` member is only read, not modified.

Comment: So does this mean that the content of the data member `contents` has been written to the `os` object ?

Comment: That’s what should happen, yes.

Comment: Ok i read it the other way round . Thanks

Comment: The other way around is when using an InputStream. To remember it more easily: the data moves in the direction of the operator , i.e. os << data writes data to os and is >> data reads from is into data.

Comment: I was about to ask the same . So if i understand it correctly then we won't be able to write `is>>contents` inside the const member function, right?

Comment: Yes, that should not be possible in a const member function.